# Increase spaces above and below theorems

Tags: spacing

I realize that the spacing between my theorems and the remaining texts of the document is so small and below is the latex code in question. I need there to be some reasonable space above and below every theorem environment that I create, so that the theorems will not be so much close to the remain texts of the document as they currently are.I have tried to find a source to solve my problem but to no avail. I will be grateful if someone helps me out. Thanks

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4 paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering Contents}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{centering}
\title{}
\end{centering}
\maketitle
\author{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE, could you bring in the scripts as text instead of an image? so that we can help you, instead of starting to type them?

Comment: Please, don't add images of code. Rather, complete the example so that the too small spaces are visible: there's no theorem in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create your own theoremstyle by `\newtheoremstyle` in `amsthm` package. See section 4.3 of amsthdoc.pdf, which is located in your MiKTeX folder. Here is the quotation.

The amsthm package provides a `\newtheoremstyle` command to aid in the
creation of custom styles, should the three predeﬁned styles prove insufficient.
The following example illustrates the use of the `\newtheoremstyle` command.

```
\newtheoremstyle{note}% name
{3pt}% Space above
{3pt}% Space below
{}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\itshape}% Theorem head font
{:}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head
{}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
```

P.S. You have two `\usepackage{amsthm}` in your example, btw.